# Converting Docx to PDF getting spacing issues

Tags: pdf, ms-word, apache-poi, docx4j

I am trying to convert a document to PDF using apache POI or Docx4j ( Apache FOP) both are giving issues while conversion.

While using apache POI it leaves line spaces when it is not there in document also.
But while using Apache FOP the table heading and table is getting shifted on next page.

I am new to this.
Can you advise which one would be better and how to avoid these spaces.

Here are code samples

SampleCode1 using apache POI

```
try
{ 
  oLog.error("function POI begin"); 
  
  String WordDocFile= "C:\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\TestDocument.docx";

  oLog.error("WordDocFile is"+WordDocFile); 

  String pdfDocFile="C:\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\TestDocument.pdf";

  oLog.error("pdfDocFile is"+pdfDocFile); 

  InputStream iStream= new FileInputStream(WordDocFile);

  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfDocFile);
  
  org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument document=new org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument(iStream);

   oLog.error("Loaded XWPFDocument");

  org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions options= org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions.create() ;

   

  org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,os,options);
   
  iStream.close();
  os.close();

  return "Success";

}

catch(Exception e)
{

  e.printStackTrace();

  oLog.error("print exception"+e);

  return "FAIL";

}
```

SampleCode2 using Docx4j

```
try
{ final org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();

   
  String WordDocFile= "C:\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\TestDocument.docx";

  String pdfDocFile="C:\\PRPCPersonalEdition\\tomcat\\TestDocument.pdf";
  
  InputStream iStream= new FileInputStream(WordDocFile);
  
  org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage pack = org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(iStream);

  org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart docPart = pack.getMainDocumentPart();
  
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfDocFile);

  org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(pack,os);
  
  iStream.close();

  os.close();

  return "Success";

}
catch(Exception e)
{

  e.printStackTrace();

  oLog.error("print exception"+e);

  return "FAIL";
}
```

#Sample Code 3 using itext
try
{
java.util.List lstInputStream = new java.util.ArrayList < java.io.InputStream > ();

oLog.error("function PDF iText begin");

String WordDocFile= "C:\PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\DraftMin.docx";

String pdfDocFile="C:\PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\DraftMinItext12.pdf";

InputStream iStream= new FileInputStream(WordDocFile);

oLog.error("Read Input file"+iStream);

java.io.InputStream isCurrentStream = null;

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfDocFile);

java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream osCurrentStream = null;

org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument document=new org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument(iStream);

fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions options = fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions.create();

```
fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,(java.io.OutputStream)osCurrentStream, options);
```

com.itextpdf.text.Document finalDocument = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();

finalDocument.addAuthor("Your Corporation");

finalDocument.addCreationDate();

finalDocument.addProducer();

finalDocument.addCreator("System");

finalDocument.addTitle("Your Corporation");

finalDocument.setPageSize(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4);

com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy1 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy(finalDocument, (java.io.OutputStream) os);

finalDocument.open();

PRFile file = new PRFile("C:\PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\Savepdf.pdf");

```
            PROutputStream prOS = new PROutputStream(file);

            prOS.write(osCurrentStream.toByteArray());

            oLog.debug("file write");

            prOS.close();

            PRInputStream prIS = new PRInputStream(file);

            oLog.debug("file read");

            isCurrentStream = (java.io.InputStream) prIS;
            oLog.debug("casting to java.io.InputStream");

            file.delete();
```

lstInputStream.add(isCurrentStream);
java.util.Iterator < java.io.InputStream > pdfIterator = lstInputStream.iterator();

while (pdfIterator.hasNext()) {

```
     java.io.InputStream pdf = pdfIterator.next();
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader readingpdf = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdf);

   

    int n = readingpdf.getNumberOfPages();
    
    for ( int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
      oLog.error("Entered in loop"+i);
      copy1.addPage(copy1.getImportedPage(readingpdf, i));
      oLog.error("Read Page n : "+i);
      
    }
```

}

finalDocument.close();

iStream.close();

os.close();

return "Success";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();

oLog.error("print exception"+e);

return "FAIL";
}

Comment: Could you use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf instead of org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf ? The code you are using is outdated.

Comment: Post your docx somewhere?

Comment: @PJ Fanning I changed my code as per your recommendation but I am getting an exception

Comment: fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException  ( Exception added )

Comment: @JasonPlutext I have added here also https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/120A4ZHcori3apzzc_ZDI90zVOUlSHAih?usp=sharing